# Check whether a directory exists in Wix bootstrapper bundle

Tags: wix

How can I check whether a directory exists in `bundle.wxs`? The directory could be anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the DirectorySearch element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/directorysearch.html) from the Util extension.